# override jQuery.ajax from other folder/domain - issue with relative url

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, overriding, relative-path

We are loading scripts from several locations and domains, one of which is having jQuery.ajax function definition.
Call to jQuery.ajax is done from different locations and domains with relative urls, example - jQuery.ajax("my/relative/url").
This generally performs a request to url relative to where the caller is located.
My requirement is to catch specific urls starting with "/my/specific" and rewrite them, but for all others - continue as is.
What i've done is overwritten the jQuery.ajax in my code, checking the url, and calling apply with the original ajax call:

```html
            jQuery.ajax = function (url) {
                if (url) {
                    if (typeof url === "string") {
                        if (url.startsWith('/my/specific/url')) {
                            arguments[0] = url.replace('/my/specific/url', '/my/changed/url');
                        }
                        else {
                            arguments[0] = url;
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        if (url.url.startsWith('/my/specific/url')) {
                            url.url = url.url.replace('/my/specific/url', '/my/changed/url');
                        }
                    }
                }
                return _fnAjaxOrig.apply(this, arguments);
            };
```

When **relative** urls are called it the requests are coming relative to my code and not to caller code.
 
Any solution to this? 
I have no access to the callers of jquery.ajax, nor to its definition.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`$.ajaxSetup()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxSetup/) and the [`beforeSend`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) callback

> Type: `Function( jqXHR jqXHR, PlainObject settings )`
>
> A pre-request callback function that can be used to modify the jqXHR
>   (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHTTPRequest) object before it is sent. Use this
>   to set custom headers, etc. The jqXHR and settings objects are passed
>   as arguments. This is an Ajax Event. Returning `false` in the `beforeSend`
>   function will cancel the request.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  beforeSend: function(jqXhr, options) {
    if (options.url.startsWith("/your/url")) {
      options.url = "/another/url";
    }
  }
});
```

> **Note**: The settings specified here will affect all calls to `$.ajax` or
>   Ajax-based derivatives such as `$.get()`. This can cause undesirable
>   behavior since other callers (for example, plugins) may be expecting
>   the normal default settings. For that reason we strongly recommend
>   against using this API. Instead, set the options explicitly in the
>   call or define a simple plugin to do so.

Comment: Tried that - but this has same result. for specific rewrite my url it works, but for other urls , not matchin mine which are relative - it will be relative to my javascript file and not the originating javascript file

Comment: Consider the following: 
js loaded from: <domain1>/folder/util.js contains:
overrideAjaxCall()
Now another js loaded from <domain2>/otherfolder/component.js is calling:
jQuery.ajax('relative/url/1.js')
This will go to url "<domain1>/folder/relative/url/1.js" instead of "<domain2>/otherfolder/relative/url/1.js"